# How to resize x labels in a chart for display purposes

Tags: python, charts, seaborn

Is there a way to autofit x labels on a chart so they are viewable by the users? Either rotate the labels down 90 degrees or make the chart wider? My Sales departments have at least 15 characters in their name. Image attached.

```
sns.countplot(x='sales_dept', data=df)
```

[Sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7r43.png)

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this below to rotate the labels

```
ax = sns.countplot(x='sales_dept', data=df)

for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(90)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much!